# Jakarta NamedQuery cannot resolve the field from joined generic type

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I would appreciate if somebody helps to solve my problem.
Here is the thing. I use `jakarta-persistence-api-3.1.0`.

There is the super class:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractStatus{
    ...here are business fields...
}
```

There are two children:

```java
@Entity
public Status_A extends AbstractStatus{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator=STATUS_A_GENERATOR)
    @SequenceGenerator
    private long id;

}

@Entity
public Status_B extends AbstractStatus{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator=STATUS_B_GENERATOR)
    @SequenceGenerator
    private long id;

}
```

So, each `<? extends AbstractStatus>` Entity has it’s own Id with specific generator.

There is abstract superclass for `AbstractProduct` that has `AbstractStatus` joined:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractProduct<ST extends AbstractStatus>{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name=“productStatusId”)
    pivate ST status;

}
```

And there is specific `Product_A` with `NamedQuery` on it:

```java
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = “Query”, query = “SELECT product
FROM Product_A product
WHERE product.status.id = 42”)
public class Product_A extends AbstractProduct<Status_A>{
}
```

And the problem here that it cannot resolve `.id` field of the `product.status` because it doesn’t know what the implementation of the `AbstractStatus` to look at, seems, it cannot resolve generic type on compile time.
If run such code in a test it will fail with

```
Cannot resolve attribute ‘id’ of ‘AbstractStatus’ due to the attribute being declared in multiple subtypes [Status_A, Status_B]
```

Comment: Just an idea, worth a try: Does it work if you add abstract getId/setId to AbstractStatus?